# Identify foreign JQuery function that fires onclick in wordpress theme

Tags: jquery, function, event-listener, callstack, javascript-debugger

I am using a different lightbox then my theme wants me to use. Everything is working correctly after I added the new lightbox except for one thing i cant really find.

**Live Example:** https://www.manufaktur13.com/produkt/camo-pusher-bag/

When you click on the thumbnails at the bottom area(middle) the lightbox comes up and displays the images correctly but the theme built in scripts also changes the main image at the top of the product page.

**How can I stop this?** (and for better understanding this whole console thing my advanced question is **how can i detect what function in what script does this?**)

I tried to look through the scripts, pause the execution in the console and set an event listener for clicks but theres so many information in the call stack thats confusing me even more...

***A little update:*** I think it comes from the frescojs/fresco lightbox but i still dont know how to kill it.

Comment: search `.product-images-carousel` in your javascript code, it should bring you to the place where the event is being added

Comment: Hi, what you mean with "your"javascript code. I have no local installation of this project. In which js is this hiding or how can i globally search across all scripts?

Comment: This is the file `https://www.manufaktur13.com/wp-content/themes/shopkeeper-m13/js/scripts-dist.js`.